# Orderby is defaulting to DESC in Wordpress/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using foreach and setup_postdata in the loop to display post. The $args sorting is by 'post_in' but the output is showing in default DESC order of Post IDs in SQL.

Here is the output:

Before args

```
Array ( [0] => 229 [1] => 226 [2] => 228 [3] => 227 [4] => 225 )
```

After args

```
Array ( 
  [post_type] => movies
  [post_in] => Array ( 
    [0] => 229 
    [1] => 226 
    [2] => 228 
    [3] => 227 
    [4] => 225 
  ) 
  [orderby] => post_in 
)
```

Query dump

```
string(275) "
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpxc_posts.ID 
  FROM wpxc_posts 
 WHERE 1=1 
   AND wpxc_posts.post_type = 'movies' 
   AND (wpxc_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
 OR wpxc_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' 
 OR wpxc_posts.post_status = 'private') 
 ORDER 
    BY wpxc_posts.post_date DESC 
 LIMIT 0, 10"
```

Actual Sequence

```
229  
228
227
226
225
```

The code is as below:

```
<?php
$postidsstring = get_field('post_ids_to_be_included');
$postidsarray = explode(", ",$postidsstring);
echo "Before args <br>";
print_r($postidsarray);
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'movies',
    'post_in' => $postidsarray,
    'orderby' => 'post_in'
);
$myposts = get_posts($args);
?><br><?php
echo "After args <br>";
print_r($args);
echo "<br>Query dump<br>";
$query = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($query->request);
echo "<br> Actual Sequence";
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
global $post;
setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<li>
<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>
</li>   
<?php endforeach;
?>
```

Please suggest how to control the sorting in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in the query you posted that it's not sorting by the IDs (or even filtering by them), rather by the `post_date`:

```
ORDER BY wpxc_posts.post_date DESC
```

I believe the issue is a double underscore - [note that `post_in` is not in the spec, whereas `post__in` is.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). Try using this instead:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'=> 'movies',
  'post__in' => $postidsarray,
  'orderby' => 'post__in'
);
```